# Doubt on choice of $L_1$ regularization parameter for lasso

Tags: regression, lasso, overfitting

In [this](http://gautampendse.com/software/lasso/webpage/pendseLassoShooting.pdf) paper, on page $14$, I have some doubts in "**How to choose $\lambda$**" part. The author says

> Let $\beta^{(−i)}_{lasso}$ be the LASSO solution obtained using $(X^{(−i)},y^{(−i)})$.

How can we solve the LASSO even after partitioning the data if we still don't have $\lambda$? What value of $\lambda$ do we use here?

Comment: the author is just describing cross validation so that would be done for a range of $\lambda$s

Comment: Welcome to the community. As @jld said, the author describes (a bit too succinctly) a standard CV procedure. Please see my answer for a few more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimal $\lambda$ is picked as *"the one that  minimizes  the
average cross validated mean squared error"* (quote from the linked paper). In addition to that, through the CV partitioning we can still pick a "candidate" $\lambda$ (and the associated $\beta^{(-i)}$) such that it minimises the MSE within the particular $i$-th fold. The author could be a bit more specific as to the fact that multiple candidate $\lambda$'s are used sequentially and/or that  $\beta^{(-i)}$ minimizes the error against $y^{(-1)}$ but the overall paragraph is not wrong. :)

Comment: We will pick the $\lambda$ that minimises MSE with respect to this partitioning, then other $\lambda's$ which minimise MSE with respect to other partitionings, and then take the overall minimising $\lambda$. Is that the case??

Comment: Yes, that is the case.

Comment: Thank You very much !